# HttpUrlconnection.getOutPutStream and getInputStream taking time in 2G/3G/4G in android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am working on android application,I have login post request is there in this request i need to send params in body for this i am using httpurlconnection in wifi it is fast but in mobile networks, first request is taking more time if i debug the code it is taking more time while doing httpurlconnection.getOutputStream and getinputstream is it a standard behaviour or can i optimize it

code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://sampleurl.com");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstParam", paramValue1));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("secondParam", paramValue2));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("thirdParam", paramValue3));

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getQuery(params));
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();

conn.connect();
private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: only first request takes more time with mobile networks or all request like that ?

Comment: only first request after that if i hit same request it is taking less time

Comment: is http://sampleurl.com the real url  you are using

Comment: i changed url but every url it is taking that much time for first request